# How to move to the next value in a loop when using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, loops, java-8, iteration, java-stream

When using external iteration over an java collectios we use keyword "continue" for move to the next value in a loop. What about in the case, when we use java stream API? Example:

```
List<User> users;

for(Item item : item){
    users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getName().equals("Tom"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(move to the next value in a outer loop(items) ???? like **continue**;);

    more code here...
}
```

Without stream:

```
 for(Item item : item){
    for(User user : users){
     if(user.getName("Tom") exist = true;
    }
  if (exist) continue;

    more code here...
}
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly? What you want to do after you find any match ?

Comment: `findFirst()` returns just a single element (if present). If you want to iterate over all the elements, use `forEach()`.

Comment: I want to skip itteration, if user.getName().equals("Tom"), only one itteration, and move to next item

Comment: so you want to get the *next* entry after `Tom`?

Comment: still unclear... show how you would do it without streams.

Answer (score 2):

The Stream-API doesn't provide the iteration mechanism like the [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) does, for this you have to use the `Iterator<User>`. However, it's good to filter the correct values first.

```
List<User> filteredUsers = users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getName().equals("Tom"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now get an `Iterator<User>` and iterate through.

```
Iterator<User> iterator = filteredUsers.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    User user = iterator.next()
    // Take a control over the further iteration here...
}
```

---

**Edit:**

According to your edit, you want to find out if any User has a name `Tom`, then perform the iteration over the `items`. Use the [`anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method which returns `true` if any element of the stream matches the predicate. It accepts the same predicate as the [`filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) does.

```
if (users.stream().anyMatch(user -> user.getName().equals("Tom"))) {
    for (Item item : item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Edit2: As @Bohemian has correctly noted, consider checking the presence of the element with each iteration since there may be an element with `"Tom"` added and the condition no longer remains `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Java stream api is used only to work on that particular stream of elements. You can never use it for control statements like ‘break’ or ‘continue’ to control external loops (like here you want to control ‘Item’ loop).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want:

```
for (Item item : item){
    if (users.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getName().equals("Tom"))) {
        continue;
    }

    // more code here...
}
```

Comment: I'd firstly evaluate the condition and *then* enter the loop.

Comment: @Nikolas except "more code here" might add Tom to users.

Comment: @Boheamian: A very good point! :)) +1.. It depends that "more code here" really does.